# Android Studio Gradle build failing when trying to include local library

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

The error I am getting is:
Gradle 'MyProject' project refresh failed:
Project with path 'libraries:mylibrary_sdk' could not be found in project':myproject'

This is my settings gradle

```
include ':libraries:mylibrary_sdk',':myproject'
```

Top level build gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9+'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

myproject build gradle

```
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1'
    compile project ("libraries:mylibrary_sdk")
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}
```

mylibrary_sdk build gradle

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
     }
     buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

I have read over all the similar answers but I am still stuck on this issue. If I remove compile project ("libraries:mylibrary_sdk") and the libraries:mylibrary_sdk include then myproject builds fine, just without access to mylibrary. The libraries folder is at the same level as settings.gradle, the top level build.gradle and the folder with myproject. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to change dependencies as  -                                          dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1'
    compile project (":libraries:mylibrary_sdk")
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, adding in answer..it might help someone later

```
dependencies { compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1' compile project (":libraries:mylibrary_sdk") }
```